# XQuery Month function

Tags: xml, xquery

I have following DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE guests [
<!ELEMENT Guest (Gname, youth+, car+)>
<!ELEMENT youth (Yname, dateofbirth)>
<!ELEMENT car (carType, excursion+)>
<!ELEMENT excursion (week, location)>
<!ELEMENT Gname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Yname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dateofbirth (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT carType (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT week (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT location (#PCDATA)>
>]
```

and i want to use XQuery to find name of all guests who have a youth whose birthday is in August. this is what i came up with:

```
for $x in Guest/youth
let $GuessN := $x/@Gname
where $x/month:=8
return <Gname> $GuessN </Gname>
```

and

```
For $x in Guest/youth[month=8]
Return <Gname>$x/@Gname </Gname>
```

is there any function to read Month ?

Comment: According to your DTD the element `youth` does not have a child `month` which your xpaths are implying. Are you trying to extract the month from `dateofbirth`? If so, what format is the date in (xs:dateTime)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check the month in `youth/dateofbirth` (see my comment above) you can use either:

`month-from-date()` if `dateofbirth` is `xs:date` or
 
`month-from-dateTime()` if `dateofbirth` is `xs:dateTime`

Example of xs:date:        `2012-06-14`
Example of xs:dateTime: `2012-06-14T22:34:52.682-06:00`

If `dateofbirth` castable as xs:date or xs:dateTime, you'll have to extract the month manually (most likely using `tokenize()`).

Here's an example using `month-from-date()`. I had to add the element declaration for `guests` and I had to properly close the internal subset (`]>` instead of `>]`).

**XML Input**

```
<!DOCTYPE guests [
<!ELEMENT guests (Guest+)>
<!ELEMENT Guest (Gname, youth+, car+)>
<!ELEMENT youth (Yname, dateofbirth)>
<!ELEMENT car (carType, excursion+)>
<!ELEMENT excursion (week, location)>
<!ELEMENT Gname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Yname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dateofbirth (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT carType (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT week (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT location (#PCDATA)>
]>
<guests>
    <Guest>
        <Gname>Guest 1</Gname>
        <youth>
            <Yname>Youth A</Yname>
            <dateofbirth>2012-06-14</dateofbirth>
        </youth>
        <car>
            <carType/>
            <excursion>
                <week/>
                <location/>
            </excursion>
        </car>
    </Guest>
    <Guest>
        <Gname>Guest 2</Gname>
        <youth>
            <Yname>Youth B</Yname>
            <dateofbirth>2012-08-14</dateofbirth>
        </youth>
        <car>
            <carType/>
            <excursion>
                <week/>
                <location/>
            </excursion>
        </car>
    </Guest>
    <Guest>
        <Gname>Guest 3</Gname>
        <youth>
            <Yname>Youth C</Yname>
            <dateofbirth>2000-12-25</dateofbirth>
        </youth>
        <car>
            <carType/>
            <excursion>
                <week/>
                <location/>
            </excursion>
        </car>
    </Guest>
</guests>
```

**XQuery**

```
<guests>
{
for $guest in /guests/Guest[month-from-date(youth/dateofbirth) = 8]
    return $guest/Gname
}
</guests>
```

**XML Output**

```
<guests>
   <Gname>Guest 2</Gname>
</guests>
```

---

Really the XQuery could be reduced to just:

```
<guests>{/guests/Guest[month-from-date(youth/dateofbirth) = 8]/Gname}</guests>
```